# find the sum of value from array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, mysqli

I have a cart table and wish to calculate sum of cost wherever I have status=1

```
id  cost   status
1   10     1
2   10     1
2   10     1
2   10     2
```

the code that I tried is

```
$sql01 = "SELECT * FROM cart where status='1' ";

$result01 = mysqli_query($con, $sql01);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result01) > 0) 
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result01)) 
            {
                $price = array_sum($row);
                echo "sum of cod:"; echo $price;
                echo "<br>";
            }
    }
```

the result that I am getting is

```
10
10
10
```

The result that should be is

```
30
```

Comment: You're summing all the numbers in the row, not adding up all the costs.

Comment: It shouldn't be printing `10` every time. The first line should print 12: `1 + 10 + 1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it is to calculate the sum in SQL, as inother answer. If you want to do it in PHP, you can add the `cost` column to a variable:

```
$total_cost = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result01)) {
    $total_cost += $row['cost'];
}
echo "Result: $total_cost";
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calculating the sum for each row. Instead you should try this:

```
$sql01 = "SELECT * FROM cart where status='1'";

$result01 = mysqli_query($con, $sql01);
$cost_array = array();
if (mysqli_num_rows($result01) > 0) 
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result01)) 
            $cost_array[] = $row['cost'];
    }
echo "Result: ".array_sum($cost_array);
```

Or (better!) optimize your MySQL query this way:

```
SELECT sum(cost) finalprice FROM cart where status='1' GROUP BY status
```

Now you can access your sum using `$row['finalprice']`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the query for you:

```
SELECT sum(cost) as price FROM cart WHERE status='1' GROUP BY status
```

PHP Code:

```
$sql01 = 'SELECT sum(cost) as price FROM cart WHERE status='1' GROUP BY status'
$result01 = mysqli_query($con, $sql01);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result01) > 0) 
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result01)) 
            {
                echo 'sum of cod:' . $row['price'] . '<br>';
            }
    }
```

Read more about GROUP BY in:

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions-and-modifiers.html

Answer (score 1):

It's easier than your code: In SQL you should use

```
"Select sum(cost) from cart where status = '1';"
```

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer, not if only one row is returned, just like here!

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
SELECT sum(cost) FROM cart group by status having status='1'
```